# Website shows broken after apply SSL certificate

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart, ssl

```
    I have integrated SSL to my website now website looks broken with https,
 without https only some pages are working properly cart pages unable to open
    Below are the configuration
```

[image]

If I enable secure URL in Admin then admin url doesn't work

How can I resole this issue?

Comment: Try updating your Unsecure Base Url to https: also

Comment: I tried same but it gives error - the page isn’t redirecting properly

Comment: Can you check in database that all URL are updated there as well in config table.

Comment: Yes, all URL are updated in config table